# MySQL LEFT JOIN .. ON .. CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

Im currently porting a MySQL db to another DBMS. I encountered the following query with the following structure.

```
SELECT ... FROM table1 AS tb1 
      LEFT JOIN Table2 AS tb2 
             ON tb1.x = tb2.x 
             AND tb2.y = 2 AND tb2.z = 3 ...
```

My target DBMS (DB2) "AND tb2.y = 2 AND tb2.z = 3" does not allow the following structure so i moved it to the WHERE clause. Unfortunately after moving it, the query doesn't seem to return the same rows from MySQL.

Comment: Sounds more like an error in your code than anything else. Maybe the real query could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an outer join, when moving predicates from the `ON` clause to the `WHERE` clause, you have to allow for records where the join produces no match, and therefore columns from the outer table will all be `NULL`.

I have no DB2 experience so there may be other subtleties that I'm not aware of, but this is how I would rewrite the query.  Checking for a `NULL` in the join column is a direct indicator of whether the join found a match.

```
SELECT ... FROM table1 AS tb1 
      LEFT JOIN Table2 AS tb2 
             ON tb1.x = tb2.x 
      WHERE tb2.x IS NULL
         OR (tb2.y = 2 AND tb2.z = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ... 
    FROM table1 AS tb1 LEFT JOIN Table2 AS tb2 
        ON tb1.x = tb2.x ,
        tb2.y = 2 ,
        tb2.z = 3 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting it to a `RIGHT JOIN`?

```
SELECT ... 
FROM Table2 AS tb2 
RIGHT JOIN ON table1 AS tb1 tb1.x = tb2.x 
WHERE tb2.y = 2 AND tb2.z = 3 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think DB2 does not allow a table alias with `as` (but I don't have a DB2 at hand right now)

Try

```
SELECT ... 
FROM table1 tb1 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 tb2 ON tb1.x = tb2.x AND tb2.y = 2 AND tb2.z = 3
```

(Note the missing `as` after the table names)

Edit: I just checked the DB2 manual, and the AS seems to be valid....
(But I'll leave the post for now)

Answer (score 0):

apparently DB2 will only use column names in comparisons. Perhaps you could somehow artificially create columns that have these values in the joining table? Are you getting error -338?